# Extract numbers buried in excel by count of digits

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a pretty complicated excel task I am completely stumped on. I am trying to extract a 7-digit integer from a page scrape of a PDF and the issue is that it can be surrounded by both text and other integers of varying length on either side, the only unique identifier is that it will be 7 characters in length. Here is what the column looks like:

**A**
*3411491* $159
Grey *5003195* Twin $1,399
Stock Plus Navy *5020081*

How can I get the italicized 7-digits out and into their own cell with a formula?

Comment: Use a regular expression in VBA. Need help?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a regular expression.

You'll need to reference (Tool > Reference) the "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"

Try the following code, it should give you what you want, matching any sequence of 7 digits. You'll need to modify it if it's possible to have more than one sequence of 7 digits or a sequence of more than 7 digits

```
Sub FindNumber()
' Reference: Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

Dim RegEx As Object ' VBScript_RegExp_55.regexp
Dim MatchCol As MatchCollection
Set RegEx = New RegExp


With RegEx
    .Pattern = "(.*)([0-9]{7})(.*)"
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global = True
End With

For i = 1 To 3 Step 1

    If RegEx.Test(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then


        Set MatchCol = RegEx.Execute(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value)

        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = MatchCol(0).SubMatches(1)

    End If

Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Press Alt+F11, copy the code into an empty module, check Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 option at Tools/References then use this as a User Defined Function in the next column.

```
Function ExtractNum(c As String) As String
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "(\b[\d]{7}\b)|.+?"
        If .Test(c) Then ExtractNum = Application.Trim(.Replace(c, "$1 "))
    End With
End Function
```